# A 2-page test has 7 questions. How many ways if at most 4 questions can fit on a page, the order is important, and all 7 questions must be used?

Tags: combinatorics

Here was my approach, but the book gave a different answer.

$$[(7*6*5) + (4*3*2*1)] + [(7*6*5*4) + (3*2*1)] = 1080$$

so that at most 4 questions on each page, every problem is used, and order is important.

The book gives 10,080 as the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to make the title fit. It originally said:

In how many
different ways can the test be made up if at most four questions can fit on either
page, the order of the questions is important, and all seven questions must be
used?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is $2 \times 7! = 10080$

The two is due to the number of ways of fitting pages (4 on the first 3 on the second vs 3 on the first 4 on the second), and the seven from permuting the seven questions.

Your mistake is having the addition between the sets of permutations in each page (should be a multiplication).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have two cases for number of questions per page, either 3 on first and 4 on second, or the other way round. Nothing else is possible because then one of the pages will have more than 4 questions.

**Case 1**: 3 on 1st and 4 on second

Number of ways to do this is $P(7,3)*4!$

**Case 2**: 4 on 1st and 3 on second

Number of ways to do this is $P(7,4)*3!$

These two cases are mutually exclusive (as order is defined), and hence the total number of ways would be just the sum, 10080

Comment: Why do we multiply by 4! in Case 1 and by 3! in Case 2? Is it for the remaining questions on the second page?

Comment: Because in case 1, that would be the number of permutations of the questions on the second page , similarly for case 2